# classes interaction methods php

Tags: php, class, oop

Lets say we have class B which extends class A. When creating new instance of class B and providing value into it that value is used in constructor of class A. Please check sample below.
I'm little bit confused about such behavior. If method "display" do not pass value into class A it should not get there, or am i missing something?

```
class A {
    protected $changeableString = 'initial value';

    public function __construct($providedText)
    {
    $this->changeableString = $providedText;        
    }

    public function printString(){
        echo $this->changeableString;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function display(){
        echo $this->changeableString;
    }
}

$test = new B('provided value');
$test->display();
```

edit: I have changed function __construct from protected to public according comments. It is indeed gives error, so if someone will review this issue now code is correct.

Comment: Your question is worded as though you don't understand **how** this works, but because the constructor is marked protected, the code **will not** work. Can you please clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: This will error out unless you are doing this in some other child class(which is vague).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the topic you are talking about is called `Inheritance` in Object-Oriented Programming (OOP).

If class `B` has no construct (`__construct`) then PHP will call the construct of class `A`.

And about `display` function, think of it as an addition to everything in class `A` but will not be available in class `A`
So class `B` is like class `A` but has one more function called `display`.

Note:
As [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160774/brian) said, if you try to call `new B('provided value')` that will produce the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to protected A::__construct() from global scope in ..
```

and to solve it just make the construct of class `A` public so class `B`.

Comment: As per the comment the code in the question will actually error as B is trying to access a protected function(the constructor). I am assuming you missed that detail.